# efficient filtering by date range in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, datetime, indexing

A large dataframe has a `date` column. By using `pandas.read_csv(..., parse_dates=["date"])` to read the data, I assume the column has been converted to an efficient data type for representing dates.

The task is now to select all items that fall into a date range, e.g. `("2018-01-01", "2018-12-31")`. This could be extremely fast by having the `date` column in sorted form and using binary search to locate the bounding indices.

But how do I tell this to pandas? Is it enough to sort by the column and perform a query on it? Should I make it a `pandas.DateTimeIndex` and use `.loc`?

One possible caveat is that the items already have a `MultiIndex` that needs to be kept intact. Also, I don't want more than one copy of the dataframe in memory.

Comment: Have you tried with `numpy` and `searchsorted`?
Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28031346/search-for-elements-by-timestamp-in-a-sorted-pandas-dataframe

Comment: @Nicolás I will try. But I'm also curious whether it is really necessary to go to numpy.

Comment: Use a Boolean Series with `.loc`, checking if `df['date'].between("2018-01-01", "2018-12-31")`, or really just if `df.date.dt.year==2018`

Comment: @clstaudt Nupy supports Pandas in many ways, so it's not so strange to use `numpy` straight away

Comment: @Nicolás I agree it is not strange. Yet I am hoping to learn something about pandas DataFrame here: Is there a way to set up the DataFrame so that `df dot get me the items from start_date to end_date` is efficient. Using numpy.searchsorted is doable but not straightforward enough.

Comment: @ALollz is that efficient, i.e. O(log(n)) and not O(n)?

Comment: No, a Boolen mask is ~O(n). This post has some useful information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45240803/pandas-dataframe-search-is-linear-time-or-constant-time

Comment: @ALollz What you are suggesting is the status quo that I am trying to beat. It's not as fast as it could be.

Comment: @ALollz Not so sure that the accepted answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45240803/pandas-dataframe-search-is-linear-time-or-constant-time is useful. Heavy abuse of O-notation and the timing experiments do not support his point, dataframe not big enough probably.